# Finding Prime numbers in a vector and print them in revers in another vector

Tags: c++, vector

here's the problem: 
x is a vector with n elements.. build another vector, y, which will contain prime elements from x, but in reverse order.
My code. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Vs code]

Comment: Please copy and paste code into question as text, not as image. Also, how is your solution not working? Do you get compiler errors? Incorrect output?

Comment: any reason you're not using std::vector?

Comment: You should copy and paste your code as text in the question, and not insert a image. If you didn't know how to edit the text, you could only have inserted it and someone else would have edited for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop you are using in line 16, you should decrement the value of i, i.e, i--, while you are incrementing it, which might be leading it to be an infinite loop. Also, you have not handled the condition if v[i] = 1. According to your code, it will show 1 as prime number though it shouldn't and also you have declared isPrime as out of the loop which will lead to wrong answers. Let suppose all numbers to be prime and set isPrime to 'true' for every element in the input vector.
Try this:

```
for(int i = n-1; i >= 0 ; i--){
    bool isPrime = true;
    if(v[i] == 1){
        continue;
    }
    for(int j = 2; j < v[i]; j++){
        if(v[i] % j == 0){
             isPrime = false;
             break;
        }
   }

   if(isPrime){
       y.push_back(v[i]);
   }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.  I modified the loop at some point to go from start to end to see if that works and forgot to change back the third expression of the loop when I copied the image with the code here. The problem was with that isPrime variable that was declared outside the loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check my solution of this task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool isPrime(int num)
{
    bool isPrime = 1;
    if (num <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); ++i)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 0;
        }
    }

    return isPrime;
}


std::vector<int> Primes(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            vec.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> primes = Primes(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << primes[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

So, I have function that checks if the element in vector is prime. Also I created a function that creates a reversed vector of prime numbers. I hope I get it right because you said about vectors, however, you used arrays in your program.

The output of Primes(100) :

97 89 83 79 73 71 67 61 59 53 47 43 41 37 31 29 23 19 17 13 11 7 5 3 2